# Do convergence in $L^2$ and boundedness of gradients in $L^2$ imply convergence in $W^{1,2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $s\in C(\mathbb R^d)$ and $s_n\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ be positive functions, both in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose that
$$ s_n \,\to\,s \ \textrm{ in }L^2(\mathbb R^d)\ \textrm{ as }n\to\infty\;,$$
and there exists $c\in(0,\infty)$ such that
$$ \int |\nabla s_n\,|^2  \,\leq\, c \quad \forall\,n\in\mathbb N \;.$$

Can we conclude that $s\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^d)$ ?

And, if yes, can we say that $\nabla s_n \to \nabla s\ $ in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)\ $ as $n\to\infty $ ?

Comment: Yes, $s \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ holds.  The question, of course, is why.  No, you cannot say that $D s_{n} \to Ds$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.  Think of the case when $d = 1$: then $(Ds_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is just an arbitrary bounded sequence in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, which need not even have a (norm) convergent subsequence.  (What about weak convergence, though?)

Comment: @PeterMorfe thank you, I got it. The sequence of $\nabla s_n$, being bounded in $L^2$, admits a subsequence that weakly converges to some $G$ in $L^2$ (as far as I understand, this is a property of weak convergence in Hilbert spaces). Integrating by parts one can see that $G$ is actually the weak gradient of $s$.